# How can I create resources sequantially in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Some context:
I'm developing a custom provider that allows to create `foo_network` resource.

So imagine I've got the following `tf` file that creates 2 similar resources:

```
# 1
resource "foo_network" "number-one" {
  display_name = "number_one_network"
}
# 2
resource "foo_network" "number-two" {
  display_name = "number_two_network"
}
```

When I run `tf plan / apply` I'd see:

```
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
foo_network.number-one: Creating...
foo_network.number-two: Creating...
foo_network.number-one: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
foo_network.number-two: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
```

i.e. both create requested would be executed simultaneously but unfortunately my rate limiter only allows to create 1 resource / second so I'd get `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests` error. Is there a way to set a flag or something such that the order would be:

```
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
foo_network.number-one: Creating...
foo_network.number-one: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
foo_network.number-one: Creation complete after 15s [id=123]
foo_network.number-two: Creating...
foo_network.number-two: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
foo_network.number-two: Creation complete after 15s [id=456]
Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: You can use the [`-parallelism` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html#parallelism-n) to limit parallelism.

Comment: Can I set that flag in my source code as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the amount of resources and data sources Terraform will process in parallel by using the [`-parallelism` flag](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html#parallelism-n) which defaults to 10.

You could set this to 1 and then Terraform will only process one resource at a time.

Your other option here would be to force Terraform to create dependencies between these resources in the graph by using the [`depends_on` configuration block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html). Normally this would be used to tell Terraform that resource foo needs to be created before resource bar but resource bar has no reference to anything from resource foo. But in this case you can abuse this mechanism to force a linear graph between these resources so that it will wait for each to be created first.

```
resource "foo_network" "number-one" {
  display_name = "number_one_network"
}
# 2
resource "foo_network" "number-two" {
  display_name = "number_two_network"

  depends_on = [
    foo_network.number-one,
  ]
}
```